# как изменять высоту блока в зависимости от изменения высоты двух блоков выше

Tags: html, css

Друзья, вот такой пример у меня:

```
<div class="filterform>
 <div class="title"></div>
 <div class="content"></div>
 <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Вот такой CSS:

```
.filterform{
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.buttons{
height:60px;
}
```

Высота `.title` может меняться.

Мне необходимо изменять высоту класса `.content` по такой формуле: Вся высота формы - высоту `.title` - высоту `.buttons`. Во время скролинга высота формы может меняться, поэтому js я бы не хотел применять для установки css. Как можно решить этот вопрос чистым css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.filterform {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.title {
  min-height: 60px;
  background: #000;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}

.buttons {
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterform">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="content "></div>
  <div class="buttons "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! работает!